# How to compute the covariance matrix of a random variable uniformly distributed in an ellipsoid

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, probability-distributions, contour-integration

Suppose that x is a random variable uniformly distributed in an ellipsoid
\begin{equation}
x^{T}Mx\leq\delta,
\end{equation}
where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Clearly, the mean of $x$ is zero. The covariance matrix is given by
\begin{equation}
\frac{\delta}{(n+2)}M^{-1}.
\end{equation} I want to know how to compute the covariance matrix. Anyone can give me some hint and references on it?

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{M}x/\sqrt{\delta}$ is uniformly distributed in the unit ball.

Comment: Solutions can be found in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3196145/variance-of-x-i-chosen-from-uniformly-distributed-hypersphere/3227416.